# Get the number of 'checkbox input tags' by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, checkbox, checked

I have a HTML page which have a certain number of divs and there is also one checkbox inside of each div.

Let's say:

```
<div class="yea" id="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="heh" id="chk1">YEAHEH1!</div>
<div class="yea" id="div2"><input type="checkbox" class="heh" id="chk2">YEAHEH2!</div>
<div class="yea" id="div2"><input type="checkbox" class="heh" id="chk3">YEAHEH3!</div>
```

Now I want to loop through those checkboxes and see which one is checked in JS. I've found one tutorial here http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/05/15/how-to-loop-through-checkboxes-or-radio-button-groups-via-javascript/ but it uses form element to include all those checkboxes and use form.elements.length to get the number, however in my project form is not necessary.

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.yea input[type="checkbox"]]:checked').length`

Comment: Thanks Tushar, but this doesn't work. I changed to your code to document.querySelectorAll('.heh input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length; (change .yea to .heh and deleted a ]) and made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chenhang91/tzeek1en/3/ . Could you check anything is wrong there?

Comment: @Tushar please see https://jsfiddle.net/chenhang91/tzeek1en/7/

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tzeek1en/10/). Since the class `heh` is on checkbox, you can use `.heh:checked`.

Comment: Thank you! I can see what you mean here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the CSS selector `'.yea input[type=checkbox]:checked'` like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.yea input[type=checkbox]:checked');
```

This will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) with the collection of checked inputs.

**Example:**

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll('.yea input[type=checkbox]:checked'),
    i = 0,
    len = checked.length;
  for (i, len; i < len; i++) {
    checked[i].parentNode.classList.add('checked');
  }
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="yea" id="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="heh" id="chk1">YEAHEH1!</div>
<div class="yea" id="div2"><input type="checkbox" class="heh" id="chk2">YEAHEH2!</div>
<div class="yea" id="div2"><input type="checkbox" class="heh" id="chk3">YEAHEH3!</div>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Your answer not only solves my question but also helps me loop through them. Thanks Ricky!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following javascript code.

```
var elementsToCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('heh');

for(var i = 0; i < elementsToCheck.length; i++) {
    if(elementsToCheck[i].checked) {
    // your code when the checkbox is selected goes here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response user7761868! However this code doesn't work. I see your point. I've made a jsfiddle to debug it: https://jsfiddle.net/chenhang91/tzeek1en/1/ Wanna take a look here?

Comment: It wont work because the for loop runs only once, when the document is loaded. 

This loop needs to run when ever any input checkbox is checked, i.e listen for event on checkbox.

Can you see the result: https://jsfiddle.net/tzeek1en/8/

Comment: So how should we make it work? I tried to either run it within vanilla JS or run within jQuery both didn't work?

Comment: Hi @Hang, we should listen for 'click' events on input box. The following fiddle shows an example. https://jsfiddle.net/tzeek1en/9/

Comment: Hi @user7761868! Thanks for your code! I learned JS function but I actually haven't written one in my script. All I do is keep using jQuery and ajax lol! You refreshed my way of using JS functions! Thanks!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of all checkboxes in your page use

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

to get the number use

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').length
```

to get list of all chacked checkboxes use

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

Comment: Does document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked') return an object or a number? 
https://jsfiddle.net/chenhang91/tzeek1en/5/

Comment: This will return a list of all the checkbox elements. To get the number use `.length`

Comment: Thanks for your help BiJ! I see the only difference is that you have moved document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]') to the inside of the "button click" function and added .length to it, and now it works. I then also added .length to my fiddle, and then the only difference is the position of this line of code. But I couldn't understand why putting this line inside of "button click" would work but if it is outside, it wouldn't work? The $(document).ready() will perform after the whole page has loaded anyway, doesn't it? Could you tell me why is this? :D

Comment: and by the way, I feel familiar with your name. I think you've helped me before, but just can't remember when haha! Thanks again!

Comment: @Hang :-) Glad I could be of help. Putting it outside the click function loads the state of the checkboxes at that instant only. Once you check something new then that information is not updated now. In programming terms when you update the view, your model doesn't change automatically. In order to get the new updated status you will have to call it again.

Comment: Thanks @BiJ! I think I know what's going on now. So you mean putting outside of click function will let the var to be assigned instantly after the page just loads, and in this case, there are no checkboxes that are selected by default, so it would give a zero. But once we click the submit button, the code inside of that click function will run and check for how many checkboxes are selected and give a correct number, however, the var outside of that click function will remain unchanged for the number of checked boxes when the page just loads, and in this case, 0. Nice! :D

Comment: @Hang Yes exactly.